# Ссылка на блог из справки ведёт на отсутствующую страницу

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка

В [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) указано: В день можно заработать до 200 баллов репутации любым сочетанием приведенных ниже действий. Конкурсы, [принятые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) и [бонусы за подключения к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) не ограничены дневным пределом репутации. По ссылке на подключение аккаунтов нет информации.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Скорее всего, когда в 2010м году выкатили [автоматическую ассоциацию аккаунтов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/19/new-automatic-account-association/), пост про ручную ассоциацию удалили. Ссылку поправим.

Comment: @Nofate ну и когда же?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а тут мои полномочия — всё

Comment: @Nofate сколько дней нужно на правку?

Comment: Вопрос не ко мне.

Comment: Теперь знаем, 21 день )